# Qual a diferença entre os métodos de string find() e index() em Python?

Tags: python, string

Eu sempre uso o método `index()` para buscar o índice de um caractere em uma *string* em Python. Recentemente, descobri o método `find()` e notei que ele faz exatamente a mesma coisa. Exemplo:

```py
name="Alan Turing"

print(name.index(n))
print(name.find(n))
```

Ambos retornam 3.

Existe alguma diferença nesses métodos que não estou conseguindo enxergar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eles servem para o mesmo propósito, a diferença está na semântica quando ocorre um erro por não achar o que estava procurando.

O `find()` retorna a posição -1, portanto depois de fazer a busca você deve testar se o resultado foi esse antes de fazer qualquer operação com ele, porque se não for um valor positivo, provavelmente não é o que desejava. Ele é melhor usado quando se espera que não ache o alvo em algumas situações, ou seja, a operação é um valor inválido, porém que há chance de acontecer, você sabe disso.

O `index()` gera uma exceção se não achar, e só não quebrará a aplicação se ela for tratada. Aí a maioria das pessoas pensarão: "então é só tratar". Pode ser em alguns casos, mas provavelmente de uma forma genérica, porque isso é um erro de programação ou algo muito fora do esperado. Esse método só deve ser usado quando você sabe que o que procura sempre será achado, portando se não achar é um problema sério na aplicação. Então use e confie que achou, se não achar, deixe a aplicação quebrar, ou trate antes pra ficar bonitinho, mas não tome decisões de regras de negócios com essa exceção.

Quando eu vejo coisas desse tipo eu percebo que em alguns momento Python tentou tomar a decisão certa sobre o uso de exceção. Pena que nem sempre é assim.