# Como procurar nome completo em List com nome "incompleto"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Eu queria fazer uma programa de Python para encontrar nome especifico em List:

Exemplo usando nomes aleatórios:

```
nomes = ['Melissa Renata Peixoto', 'Bruna Carla Henry Gomes', 'Carla Rosângela Brito', 'Carla Letícia Sebastiana Assis']
```

Usando assim `nomes.find("Carla")`

Deve aparecer no output:

```
Carla Rosângela Brito
Carla Letícia Sebastiana Assis
Bruna Carla Henry Gomes
```

Eu tentei programar assim:

```
while i != 4:
    x = nomes[i].find("Carla")
    if x == 0:
        print(nomes[i])
    else:
        pass
    i+=1
```

Mas não apareceu "Bruna **Carla** Henry Gomes" no output

Comment: é pq vc está pegando apenas os casos em que `Carla` é o primeiro nome (index=0). Use `if!=-1` como condição porque o `find` retorna -1 quando não encontra a substring. Veja essa questão:https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/487894/qual-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-os-m%c3%a9todos-de-string-find-e-index-em-python

Comment: Outro detalhe é que `else: pass` é desnecessário e pode ser removido - `pass` basicamente é o mesmo que "não faz nada" e geralmente serve para designar um bloco vazio quando a sintaxe da linguagem exige que se tenha algo. Mas como o `else` não é obrigatório, e não é para fazer nada se não entrar no `if`, então remova esse `else: pass` daí. Por fim, dá pra fazer mais simples: https://ideone.com/Re0U3U